# Want to show Top level/Parent Lables on Header menu - docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

it is possible to show 1st level sidebar categories in Header menu? like "Introduction, Category 1, Category 2" want to show this three labels or it may be more .. in above header menu?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#navbar-doc-sidebar